can't tell if it is array or pointer raylib
I am facing problem by learning raylib and trying to make most simple platformer this is the code that I wrote in C language not C++ again repeating C not C++ and pls solve this error quickly don't use chat got it is not right and pls explain in easy solution and explain it simpily.
#include "raylib.h"

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Program main entry point
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    float size;
    int velocity;
}Ball;
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    
}Platform;
int ball_on_ground(Ball ball, Platform platform[]){
    int count = sizeof(platform)/sizeof(Platform);
    for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
        Platform platform = platform[i];
        Rectangle platform_rec = {.x = platform.x, platform.y, .width = platform.width, .height = platform.height};
        Vector2 ball_position = {.x = ball.x, .y = ball.y};
        int ballbottom = ball.y + ball.size;
        if (CheckCollisionCircleRec(ball_position, ball.size, platform_rec)){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    Ball ball = {
        .x = width/2,
        .y = height/2,
        .size = 40.0,
        .velocity = 4
    };
    int gravity = 2;
    Platform platforms[3];
    platforms[0].x = 0;
    platforms[0].y = height-10;
    platforms[0].width = width;
    platforms[0].height = 10;
    
    platforms[1].x = abs(width*0.1);
    platforms[1].y = abs(height*0.7);
    platforms[1].width = abs(width*0.3);
    platforms[1].height = abs(height *0.05);
    
    platforms[1].x = abs(width*0.1);
    platforms[1].y = abs(height*0.7);
    platforms[1].width = abs(width*0.3);
    platforms[1].height = abs(height *0.05);
    InitWindow( width, height, "MyGame" );
    SetTargetFPS( 60 );
    while(!WindowShouldClose()){
        BeginDrawing();
        int ballbottom = ball.y + ball.size;
        if(ball_on_ground(ball, platforms)){
            ball.velocity = 0;
            //ball.y =  height - ball.size;
            if(IsKeyPressed(KEY_SPACE)){
                    ball.velocity = -30;
                }
        }
            if(IsKeyDown(KEY_LEFT)){
                ball.x -= 6;
                }
            if(IsKeyDown(KEY_RIGHT)){
                ball.x += 6;
            }
        
        ball.y += ball.velocity;
        ball.velocity += gravity;
        ClearBackground(WHITE);
        int count = sizeof(platforms)/sizeof(Platform);
        for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
        DrawRectangle(platforms[i].x,platforms[i].y,platforms[i].width,platforms[i].height,BLACK);}
        DrawCircle(ball.x, ball.y , ball.size, BLUE); 
        
        EndDrawing();
    }

    return 0;
}



This is the error faced by me while running the code:

BallGame.c:22:37: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   22 |         Platform platform = platform[i];



it to run succesfully and make solid platform. please don't change code much.

With Platform platform = platform[i]; you create a brand new variable named platform that shadows the argument variable of the same name. Give one of the variable some other name.

Also note that as an argument, Platform platform[]is really the same asPlatform *platform. And the size of a pointer (e.g. sizeof(platform)`) is the size of the pointer itself, not whatever data it might point to. If you need to pass an array of unknown size to a function, always include its size (number of elements) as an argument to the function.

You also have a copy-paste bug in the main function, where you initialize platform[1] twice, but don't initialize platform[2].

"can't tell if it is array or pointer". No, you can't, because an array passed to a function decays to a pointer. Even if you define int func(int array[42]) the 42 will be ignored.

I just did this:
int ball_on_ground(Ball ball, Platform platforms[]){
int count = sizeof(platforms)/sizeof(Platform);
for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
    Platform platform = platforms[i];
    Rectangle platform_rec = {.x = platform.x, platform.y, .width = platform.width, .height = platform.height};
    Vector2 ball_position = {.x = ball.x, .y = ball.y};
    int ballbottom = ball.y + ball.size;
    if (CheckCollisionCircleRec(ball_position, ball.size, platform_rec)){
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;

}

You still have the same problem with count that I pointed out before. The variable platforms is a pointer. And the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself. You must pass count as an argument.
